# Share picker like "Share page" in WP7 internet explorer

Tags: windows-phone-7, launcher, picker

Is there any way I can get a share picker like the one seen when you share a page from Internet Explorer? It allows you to choose from Messaging, individual emails, or social networks.

[This msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769550%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) lists several individual launchers (like social networks, email), but not the one higher up the chain?

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - you have to write your own.

The two best options that I found are:
1. Write your own using the primitive Popup class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup(v=vs.95).aspx

1. Use the toolkit ListPicker to simulate such a popup.
   http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth
   http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

(BTW: I am using the Popup and so far am very happy. Took a while to get it just right, but it's good once you do)

Comment: Bummer. Thanks.Is there a way to determine what email address exist on the phone, in order link directly to them rather than the email picker?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(MICROSOFT.PHONE.USERDATA.CONTACTS);k(CONTACTS);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true